# when importing OpenCV: TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, anaconda, typeerror

Trying to import OpenCV for a physics project, but I'm getting a TypeError? I'm simply putting:

```
import cv2
```

and am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 8>()
      6 from scipy.fft import fftshift
      7 import imageio
----> 8 import cv2
      9 import scienceplots
     11 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:181, in <module>
    176             if DEBUG: print("Extra Python code for", submodule, "is loaded")
    178     if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')
--> 181 bootstrap()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:175, in bootstrap()
    172 if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: binary extension... OK')
    174 for submodule in __collect_extra_submodules(DEBUG):
--> 175     if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
    176         if DEBUG: print("Extra Python code for", submodule, "is loaded")
    178 if DEBUG: print('OpenCV loader: DONE')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py:28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module(base, name, enable_debug_print)
     26 native_module = sys.modules.pop(module_name, None)
     27 try:
---> 28     py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
     29 except ImportError as err:
     30     if enable_debug_print:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/typing/__init__.py:69, in <module>
     65 import typing
     68 if numpy.lib.NumpyVersion(numpy.__version__) > "1.20.0" and sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
---> 69     NumPyArrayGeneric = numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[numpy.generic]]
     70 else:
     71     NumPyArrayGeneric = numpy.ndarray

TypeError: 'numpy._DTypeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, updated Anaconda, and checked for any potentially competing package with `pip list` and in the root. Am a physicist not a programmer, so help much appreciated!

Comment: What versions of opencv and numpy are you using?

Comment: opencv-contib-python: 4.8.0.76, numpy: 1.21.5

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/885) mentions the bug and says it will be fixed in opencv version 4.9, however it looks like that version has not been released yet...

Comment: Current version of numpy is 1.26 -- are you able to upgrade?

Comment: Just tried `pip install upgrade opencv-contrib-python` and got `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.8.0.76)`

Comment: I upgraded numpy and it worked! Thanks a bunch!